# Integral to find the area with bounded regions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use an iterated integral to find the area of the region bounded by $$4x - 7y = 0$$ $$x + y = 8$$

$$y = 0$$

I need help in starting this problem. Can someone help me start it as in give me a idea or clue how to?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Sketch a diagram. The region will look like a triangle whose base is on the $x$-axis, suggesting that we integrate with respect to $x$ first, then with respect to $y$. Note that the two oblique lines intersect at the point $(56/11, 32/11)$. Hence, we have:
$$
\int_0^{32/11} \int_{7y/4}^{8-y} dx~dy
$$

---

Note that this is equivalent to what you would have done in single-variable calculus, since this iterated integral is exactly the same as:
$$
\int_0^{32/11} [(8-y)-(7y/4)] dy
$$

Comment: how did you know to get the integral for X?

Comment: Solving the equations for $x$, you get $x=8-y$ as the rightmost line and $x=7y/4$ as the leftmost line.